# using $match in mongoose aggregate query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use $match in mongoose aggregate query.

```
Feed.aggregate([
          {$match:{"createdBy":'ObjectId("59d79b6ea918cf1e40ee041f")'}},
          {
                "$lookup":
                  {
                    "from": "comments",
                    "localField": "_id",
                    "foreignField": "feedId",
                    "as": "feedComment"
                  }
             }
          ]).exec(function(err, results){
              if(err){
                res.json({"success": false,"errorCode": errorCodes.serverError,"error": err});
              }else{
                if(results == null){
                  res.json({"success": false,"errorCode": errorCodes.dataNotFound,"error": "no record found"})
                }else{
                  res.json({"success": true,"data": results});
                }
              }
           })
```

It is giving black results array.

But without $match it works.

The feeds collection is:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d878f67e6ba32c60c7410c"),
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("59d79b6ea918cf1e40ee041f"),
        "feedKeywords" : "school,kids",
        "feedDescription" : "Going to school",
        "feedTitle" : "Going to schoo",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-07T06:49:26.100Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-07T06:49:26.100Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comments collection is like this

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d87a737e6ba32c60c7410e"),
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("59d6562dd3c2be2ba452665e"),
        "feedId" : ObjectId("59d878f67e6ba32c60c7410c"),
        "stars" : "3.5",
        "commentText" : "vewr nice",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-10-07T06:55:47.305Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-07T06:55:47.305Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Post a sample of your comments collection also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used Single Quote for the value of createdBy in the $match aggregation pipeline, so that the value would be treated as String but the data in your Feed collection for createdBy is an Object and hence the there is no data retrieved when the $match is added.

Please use this corrected query

```
Feed.aggregate([
          {$match:{"createdBy":new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59d79b6ea918cf1e40ee041f")}},
          {
                "$lookup":
                  {
                    "from": "comments",
                    "localField": "_id",
                    "foreignField": "feedId",
                    "as": "feedComment"
                  }
             }
          ]).exec(function(err, results){
              if(err){
                res.json({"success": false,"errorCode": errorCodes.serverError,"error": err});
              }else{
                if(results == null){
                  res.json({"success": false,"errorCode": errorCodes.dataNotFound,"error": "no record found"})
                }else{
                  res.json({"success": true,"data": results});
                }
              }
           })
```

Comment: (node:2780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Comment: @raju - Try now, new operator added for ObjectId creation, which was not there earlier.

Comment: @raju - Hope it should work now. I have added `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` to our new operator. The error might be due to the object was being cast using the Schema type Object Id `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` whereasa our query is expecting just a pure ObjectId `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`.

Comment: Yahoo000, Thanks a lot sir. It works. Now I can use this same funda in my other queries. Thanks again